# WebStorm modifies URLs

Tags: angularjs, webstorm, adobe-brackets

We use two IDEs for developing Angular.js applications: Brackets v1.7 + WebStorm v2016.2

When opening an application via Brackets IDE, URLs are shown as expected:

`http://127.0.0.1:55738/index.html#/distributor`

But when I open the same URL from WebStorm IDE, it comes up as follows:

`http://localhost:63342/svnSource/SRDL/index.html?_ijt=j25vtpn610cetc16cgo6btff1v#/distributor`

Why is it so different, and why is WebStorm injecting those extra parameters? Is it something optional that can be switched off?

Comment: so, use a VM resembling your production server instead of the built-in webserver. why would you use the built-in webserver anyway?

Comment: @Gordon it is the fastest option for development.

Comment: and annoying and a real pain for your team.

Comment: @Gordon it gets in the way of URL parsing, and is confusing developers, as there is no correlation with testing/production hosting. So yeah, it is a terrible feature, if it cannot be deactivated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, This is happening because JetBrains has updated some security patches to WebStorm v2016.2.

They have enable authorization for built-in server and currently Tt is not possible to disable this option according to JetBrains team.

for more details about it, Please find the below article:

https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2016/05/11/security-update-for-intellij-based-ides-v2016-1-and-older-versions/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
http://localhost:63342/svnSource/SRDL/index.html?_ijt=j25vtpn610cetc16cgo6btff1v#/distributor
```

This is the local debugging mode of the Webstorm and here what WebStorm is doing is they are running your code from built in web server of theirs and they follow that specific format.

The link that is attached extra is actually the locations of the project file where you codes are placed at.

You can have a look at the setting by going to the settings sections via opening file and then opening settings, there please look for debugging section and then make changes that are available. (I have windows)

If you wont like to use their own web server you can make use of remote debugging facilities.

> Local debugging. In this mode, the application files remain where they
>   are in the WebStorm project on you machine. WebStorm runs them on the
>   built-in Web server with the root URL http://localhost:/. The built-in server port (1024 or higher)
>   is specified on the Data Views page of the Settings dialog box. A
>   debugging session in this mode can be initiated in two ways: Open the
>   HTML file with the JavaScript injection to be tested and launch the
>   temporary run/debug configuration that WebStorm has generated
>   automatically. This approach it helpful when you do not need to debug
>   the entire application but just one script. Create and launch a
>   permanent debug configuration.

This is their documentation regarding what you are experiencing at the moment.

The remote debugging option is explained in detail in here please go through it.

[Click Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.2/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html)

Comment: How do we get into that `Run/Debug Configuration` dialog? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: You are using which OS and the debugger you are using? @vitaly-t

Comment: Okay I guess you are using JS debugger. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/configuring-javascript-debugger.html

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced same issue. I am using python builtin server on my project, instead.

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 5000
```

It seems to be doing the job...