# Why is $_GET (PHP) not empty in new directories and files?

Tags: php, phpstorm

In newly opened directories and files `$_GET` is not empty, by checking:

```php
print_r($_GET);
var_dump($_GET);
if (empty($_GET)) {
    echo '$_GET is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
} else {
    echo '$_GET is not empty';
}
```

*I get:*

```
Array ( [_ijt] => mt4q815k0l6ke5gpmebq419g12 )

array (size=1)
'_ijt' => string 'mt4q815k0l6ke5gpmebq419g12' (length=26)
```

`$_GET` is not empty

Please explain the reason for this result. I use PhpStorm.

Comment: A quick search found this, suggesting your IDE is adding the param https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38585590/webstorm-modifies-url-s

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is this problem serious? How to find a way out of this situation?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using WAMP and will try Open Server

Answer (score -1):

This occurs because your IDE has updated some patches. Try to run the application on an external server like XAMPP, not IDE built-in server.